# Comparar datas e validar somente o mesmo ano

Tags: java, jsf

No meu componente `p:calendar` existe dois intervalos de datas `dtInicial` e `dtFinal` no managed bean preciso comparar somente os anos e validar. Caso seja o mesmo ano, mostrar a mensagem de "ok". Caso contrário, "anos diferentes".

---

```
private int getYear(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}

    boolean hasInterval = sourceReq.getDtInicial() != null 
            && sourceReq.getDtInicial() != null;
    if (hasInterval){
        int dtIni = getYear(sourceReq.getDtInicial());
        int dtFin = getYear(sourceReq.getDtFinal());

        if (dtIni != dtFin){
            showErrorMessage("Favor informar o mesmo Ano para Pesquisa.", true);
            return false;
        }           

    }
```

Comment: jsp? Pode adicionar como está seu código?

Comment: Poisé Marcos, verificando sua dúvida imaginei que seria jsp também.

Comment: são 2 `<p:calendar>` um para dtInicial e outro para dtFinal?

Comment: se for, esse componente do primefaces trabalha com a classe `Date` do pacote java.util.

Answer (score 0):

o que você poderia fazer era

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String dataInicial = formatter.format(dtInicial)
String dataFinal = formatter.format(dtFinal)
if(dataInicial.equals(dataFinal)){
   //Coloque aqui sua mensagem de ok, já que os anos das duas datas são iguais
}else{
   //Coloque aqui seu tratamento para mensagem diferente
}
```

Explicando o que eu fiz:

**1º** : declarei um SimpleDateFormat com o pattern("yyyy") pra utilizar o método format(), que recebe um Date e retorna uma String com o valor da data passada no pattern passado(no caso, somente o ano da data. 'yyyy')

**2º** : atribui o retorno do método format() para as variáveis dataInicial e dataFinal com seus respectivos parâmetros.

**3º** : fiz o teste pra saber se essas variáveis são equivalentes ou não, caso sejam, os anos são iguais, caso contrário, não são.